# Incorporating dim parameter of torch.topk in tf.nn.top_k

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

Pytorch provide `torch.topk(input, k, dim=None, largest=True, sorted=True)` function to calculate `k` largest elements of the given `input` tensor along a given dimension `dim`.

I have a tensor of shape `(16, 512, 4096)` and I am using `torch.topk` in the following manner-

```
# inputs.shape (16L, 512L, 4096L)
dist, idx = torch.topk(inputs, 64, dim=2, largest=False, sorted=False)
# dist.shape (16L, 512L, 64L), idx.shape (16L, 512L, 64L)
```

I found similar tensorflow implementaion as following - `tf.nn.top_k(input, k=1, sorted=True, name=None)`.

My question is how to Incorporate `dim=2` parameter in `tf.nn.top_k` so as to achieve the tensor of the same shape as calculated by pytorch?

Answer (score 1):

`tf.nn.top_k` works on the last dimension of the input. This means that it should work as is for your example:

```
dist, idx = tf.nn.top_k(inputs, 64, sorted=False)
```

In general you can imagine the Tensorflow version to work like the Pytorch version with hardcoded `dim=-1`, i.e. the last dimension.

However it looks like you actually want the k *smallest* elements. In this case we could do

```
dist, idx = tf.nn.top_k(-1*inputs, 64, sorted=False)
dist = -1*dist
```

So we take the k largest of the *negative* inputs, which are the k smallest of the original inputs. Then we invert the negative on the values.